Temporary change to grep-find-command à la (let ((grep-find-command ...)) ...)
I'm trying to define a function that runs grep-find using a temporary value for grep-find-command.  The following almost works:
;; "fe" is the "iron searcher" that I use internally.
;; You use it to find ferrous bueller.
(defun fe (command-args)
  (interactive
   (progn
     (let ((grep-find-command "fe ")
           (grep-find-template grep-find-template)
           (grep-host-defaults-alist grep-host-defaults-alist)
           (grep-command grep-command)
           (grep-template grep-template)
           (grep-use-null-device grep-use-null-device)
           (grep-find-use-xargs grep-find-use-xargs)
           (grep-use-null-filename-separator grep-use-null-filename-separator)
           (grep-highlight-matches grep-highlight-matches)
           (grep-quoting-style grep-quoting-style))
       (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command grep-find-command)
       (eval (cadr (interactive-form #'grep-find))))))
  (grep-find command-args)
  (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command grep-find-command))

except if I abort or if grep-find throws an error, grep-find-command fails to revert to defaults because the stuff after the grep-find statement doesn't execute.  Doing something involving condition-case is the only solution that comes to mind but trying to figure out how to use that special form almost destroys my brain and I'd rather avoid it if possible.
I'd also love to cut down on that let statement from heck.
EDIT: Tue May 28 18:30 EDT (-0400) 2024
I did a condition-case thing per @NickD.  This seems to work for me but I'll report back later if it doesn't.  A way to simplify this and/or not have to specify all the grep and grep-find related variables would be awesome.
(defun fe (command-args)
  (interactive
   (progn
     (require 'grep)
     (condition-case err
         ;; required here to capture when someone presses
         ;; C-g (keyboard-quit) at the pattern input, and restores
         ;; grep-find-command et al. in that event.
         (progn
           (let ((grep-find-command "fe ")
                 (grep-find-template grep-find-template)
                 (grep-host-defaults-alist grep-host-defaults-alist)
                 (grep-command grep-command)
                 (grep-template grep-template)
                 (grep-use-null-device grep-use-null-device)
                 (grep-find-use-xargs grep-find-use-xargs)
                 (grep-use-null-filename-separator grep-use-null-filename-separator)
                 (grep-highlight-matches grep-highlight-matches)
                 (grep-quoting-style grep-quoting-style))
             (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command grep-find-command)
             (eval (cadr (interactive-form #'grep-find)))))
       (t (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command grep-find-command)
          (signal (car err) (cdr err))))))
  (condition-case err
      (grep-find command-args)
    (t (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command grep-find-command)
       (signal (car err) (cdr err))))
  (grep-apply-setting 'grep-find-command grep-find-command))


You are right: you have to catch the errors and condition-case is the way to do it. You'll just have to bite the bullet and learn about it. In the let, everything after the first entry is of the form (x x)  - why do you do include those entries?

@NickD The (x x) parameters create dynamic scopes for those variables so that they contain their present values.  Omitting the value sets it to nil.

Try omitting the whole form: every (x x) line, not just the value. These variables are global options, and the function will be able to find the values without you having to do anything about them.
